# Empty values added to Python list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to add items to a list called 'bucket', but I can't seem to set it up correctly. The issue is as follows.

When I run the code below, the second .append() adds an empty [] for the first two iterations. Only on the third iteration, the values I want are being added.

Could anyone please tell me what I do wrong? I have been searching the forums, but can't find an answer.

FYI: this is only a snippet, and some of the mentioned lines may therefore seem nonsensical. This part of the code, however, is where my incorrect values are originating from.

Your help is much appreciated!

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
bucket = []
stock = ['x','y','z']

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

my_path = "C:\\my\\path"

for i in stock:
    htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(str("the-url-i-open" + i))
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    bucket.append(str(i))   
    bucket.append(soup.find_all(id=str("url-addition" + i)))
```

Comment: Well, it sounds like the first two times you run `soup.find_all(id=str("url-addition" + i))`, it's not finding what you think it's finding.

Comment: If it's guaranteed to append on the third just do an if to append on the third iteration.

Comment: The puzzling thing to me is that it does when I isolate the individual 'stock' items. For some reason - however long the list is - I always get the last value printed out correctly. This also means that I only get the right value on the third iteration, if the list has three items.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your

```
soup.find_all
```

fails to find any id with the string "url-additionx" and "url-additiony", which is why you're getting back an empty list.

Comment: That makes sense, except that it will return the value for y correctly until I add z. If I add another fourth value now, the third one is not returned anymore.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line: htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(str("the-url-i-open" + i))
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles across something similar, it was actually quite a silly mistake.

`the soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)` part was the problem. I passed `htmltext` to `BeautifulSoup` and then tried to redefine it later. The fact that I always saw the *last* value most likely had to do with the fact that I was rerunning the script, and therefore the last value was assigned to a new iteration.

Thanks for the comments!